# How do I correct these errors so that I can install conky? ( my weather is installed ok )

Tags: 12.04, conky

```
dpkg: warning: files list file for package my-weather-indicator' 
missing, assuming package has no files currently installed.
(Reading database ... 95%dpkg: unrecoverable fatal error, aborting:
files list file for package nitrux-icon-theme' contains empty filename
W: Waited for dpkg --assert-multi-arch but it wasn't there - dpkgGo (10: No child processes)
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (2)
A package failed to install.  Trying to recover:
```

Nitrux icons have been removed previously

Answer (score 6):

If you're having problems updating in Ubuntu do this:

Remove the file nitrux-icon-theme.list in /var/lib/dpkg/info/, and update your package cache.

The packages have been updated since, so do that, and re-install it.

Comment: Thank you very much. Your answer put me in the right direction. Conky has installed with no known issues.

Comment: This is the correct answer.  Nothing else fixed my issue... mine was with a Raspberry Pi B+ and 'lxde-icon-theme' missing, but was the same exact situation and fix: remove `lxde-icon-theme.list` from `/var/lib/dpkg/info/`, run `sudo apt-get update` and problem solved!  Thank you!

Comment: I was having this same problem when installing LAMP on Raspbian. This fix worked for me. +1